# Simple example of a complex situation in Unit Testing, how should this be designed?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, oop, single-responsibility-principle

I've simplified the code in the example to keep the question shorter, but basically I am struggling with designing more testable code and isolating them from each other.

With just two methods here listed below I've outlined exactly what tests I need to do.

1. Verify that the correct URL was utilized
2. Verify the appropriate headers were used, such as the request was in JSON.
3. Verify a POST request was used  (I have a HttpMessageHandler and using delegates to intercept and mock out the internet as a dependency in the actual code)
4. Verify that the serialized JSON value doesn't have any extra properties not filled out.

The code example is below:

```cs
class RESTAPI
{
    private IHttpService _webService;

    public void ChangeAssignedAgent(ITicket ticket, string agentName)
    {
        string agentID = GetAgentIDFromName(agentName);
        _webService.PostRequest($"https://localhost/{agentID}", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ticket), Encoding.UTF8,"application/json"));
    }

    private string GetAgentIDFromName(string agentName)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(_webService.GetStringContent($"https://localhost/{agentName}"))["sys_id"].Value<string>();
    }
}
```

In theory, these tests should be completely isolated from each other.
But they're not because in each test, I must setup and configure GetAgentFromName() even when it is not relevant.

Here are my ideas in fixing this problem, but I am not sure what the best resolution would be to make something more SRP oriented and testable.

1. Utilize a decorator or adapter to simply convert the agentName to an agentID, then pass this information to the base class to post the request.
2. Change the private method to protected internal, have a mocking framework replace the implementation of the GetAgentIDFromName() method, and simply call the base implementation for any method that's not been mocked.
3. Change the method signature of the ChangeAssignedAgent() method to instead refer to getting an agentID instead of a name, make the GetAgentIDFromName() public and expect the consumers of your class to utilize it in order to use the ChangeAssignedAgent() method.

It's possible that the first option is the best way to tackle this scenario, but something tells me it may not be the right solution because technically the base class is misleading... it wants an agentName... not an ID.

The second option seems more of a hack and code smell to me, it is effectively testing a private method... I am not sure... open for suggestions.

Lastly, the last option... it's similar to the second option in terms how I feel it may be a hack/code smell but it makes most logical sense to me. However, with this design it feels like you can never have private methods and it may also increase complexity of your class.

Am I overthinking this? I would love to hear some suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You're always going to have to mock the dependencies you need.

One challenge here is that `IHttpService` functions like a service locator. Neither what you request from it or its response are strongly typed. That makes it a dependency that you can technically ask for anything or tell to do anything, which is why I compare it to a service locator.

It will help if instead of `IHttpService` you have a strongly-typed interface that does exactly what your class needs. Because you have two requests, it could be an interface with two methods, or two entirely separate interfaces. You can also use delegates.

Here's a rough approach that might help, or might spark something else.

First an abstraction that just says what you want to do. There are no implementation details or mention of Rest API. (The name I've given this is lame. Years ago I would have just called it `ITicketService` but that's even more generic.)

```
public interface ITicketRepository
{
    void ChangeAssignedAgent(ITicket ticket, string agentName);
    string GetAgentIDFromName(string agentName);
}
```

I made the second method part of the interface. You're going to want to test it separately or be able to mock it separately, so that accomplishes it. If you don't want it to be part of the same interface you can always create another one. I also like using multiple delegates instead of a single interface. More on that [here](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2018/03/18/depending-on-functions-instead-of-interfaces.html).

Then the implementation can be an HttpClient. I used the RestSharp NuGet package. I haven't tested this (and can't since I don't have the API) so view this as a starting point. What it does is, to a large extent, remove the need for testing some of what you were going to test.

You could do this with any other HTTP client library. I'm just using this one because it's familiar and I know that it handles creation and disposal of HTTP clients the right way behind the scenes. (It's not creating and disposing them with each use.)

```
public class HttpClientTicketRepository : ITicketRepository
{
    private readonly string _baseUrl;

    public HttpClientTicketRepository(string baseUrl)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseUrl))
            throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(baseUrl)} cannot be null or empty.");
        _baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    public void ChangeAssignedAgent(ITicket ticket, string agentName)
    {
        var agentId = GetAgentIDFromName(agentName);
        var client = new RestClient(_baseUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(agentId, dataFormat:DataFormat.Json);
        request.AddJsonBody(ticket);
        client.Post(request);
    }
}
```

Looking at the things you wanted to test:

**Does it use the correct URL?**
You don't need to test that because the URL is injected. It doesn't come from this class.  It uses whatever URL you tell it to.

That also solves the problem where the URL would be hard-coded. You can have one for dev, one for production, etc, and inject the correct one depending on that environment. Because this class acts as a ciient it needs to know the other segments of the URL, but it will use whatever base url you tell it to.

**Verify the appropriate headers were used, such as the request was in JSON.**
You don't need to test it because it's handled by the library. Even if you were using .NET framework classes I don't think this is something you would need to test, because you'd be testing the framework, not your own code. This sort of thing can be handled in an integration test to make sure that everything works end-to-end.

**Verify a POST request was used (I have a HttpMessageHandler and using delegates to intercept and mock out the internet as a dependency in the actual code)

Verify that the serialized JSON value doesn't have any extra properties not filled out.**
See above.

Now, whatever class needs to update a ticket, it can just depend on the `ITicketRepository` which is really easy to mock.

As for testing `HttpClientTicketRepository`, there's no longer anything to mock. The only thing this does is talk to an API using HTTP, so you would test it with an integration test, pointing it at an actual instance of the API and verifying that you get the expected result. That integration test covers stuff like whether the headers and HTTP method are correct.

Comment: Thanks Scott, sort of confused. You provided two methods with the same signature which wouldn't compile. In the real class I utilize a base URL, I only omitted here to keep the code example as simple as possible because that wasn't what my question was focused on. I've already written unit tests for all of the 4 steps I mentioned. I realize people have differing opinions on what exactly needs to be tested,  but just open for ideas on how to make things more mockable when calling private methods.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error when copying code between VS and SO. Fixed.

Comment: Morning Scott, I posted an answer that I feel addresses my problem. Beyond fixing the obvious like headers and better Dependecy Injection and perhaps null object client/lazy loading, how do you feel about this solution?

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a design that allows me to do what I wanted without any "hacks" per say.

```
public class TicketService
{
    private readonly IHttpService _httpService;

    public TicketService(IHttpService httpService)
    {
        _httpService = httpService;
    }

    public async Task CreateNewTicket()
    {
        var message = new TicketRESTLinks().CreateNewTicket("Sample");
       await _httpService.SendMessage(message);
    }
}
public class HttpService : IHttpService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessage(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        if (message.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            return _client.GetAsync(message.RequestUri);
        }
        if (message.Method == HttpMethod.Post)
        {
            return _client.PostAsync(message.RequestUri, message.Content);
        }
        if (message.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            return _client.DeleteAsync(message.RequestUri);
        }
        if (message.Method == HttpMethod.Patch)
        {
            return _client.PatchAsync(message.RequestUri, message.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _client.Dispose();
    }
}

public interface IHttpService
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendMessage(HttpRequestMessage message);
}

public class TicketRESTLinks
{


    public HttpRequestMessage CreateNewTicket(string description)
    {
      return new  HttpRequestMessage()
        {
          Content =  new StringContent("sample JSON"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri =  new Uri("https://localhost/api/example"),


        };
    }
}
```

This allows me to test individually if the REST configuration is correct (I.E, it must be a POST, etc) and keeps each class with a single responsibility, it also allows me to easily mock out dependencies in testing